# EdmondsKarpMaxFlow in Jung2 throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: jung

I am trying to calculate max flows on a graph with Jung2 (and Scala), but end up with a `NoSuchElementException` being thrown. I suspect that my initialization is incorrect, but cannot tell how.

My Graph is a `DirectedSparseGraph[Long, Long]` where both nodes and vertices are simply their own unique id. I keep metadata for vertices and edges (including their weight) in a seperate HashMap.

I initialize and execute the algorithm as follows:

```
val weightTransformer = new Transformer[Long, Number]() {
  override def transform(edgeId: Long) = edges(edgeId).weight
}
var flows = Map[Long, Number]()
val edgeFactory = new Factory[Long] {
  var current = 12000000
  override def create() = {
    current += 1
    current
  }
}
val algo = new EdmondsKarpMaxFlow(graph, sourceId, sinkId, weightTransformer, flows, edgeFactory)
algo.evaluate()
```

and get `NoSuchElementException: key not found: 12000289` which originates from the algorithms finalization steps, by [calling the weight transformer](http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/jung-algorithms/xref/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/flows/EdmondsKarpMaxFlow.html#270). As you can see in the code, my edge factory generates increasing indices which are *not* already in use by my own program. Edge `12000289` from the Exception is thus some backflow-edge generated by the algorithm. How is my weight transformer supposed to know its weight?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark - but a Java Map return a `null` value when a key is not found. It seems like the algorithm checks for a `null` value on line 273. Does Scala handle missing keys differently? Could it be possible that JUNG depends on a `null` value where Scala throws an exception?